# When I host my ASP.NET code in local IIS server MessageBox.Show not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I host my asp.net code in local IIS server it showing following error:

> Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

and my code as follow:

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Really delete?", "Confirm delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
}
```

Comment: `MessageBox.Show()` in a *web application*?  That's Windows Forms code.  How did that even *compile* in ASP.NET?

Comment: @David compiling it is easy. You just add the Win Forms reference and voila!

Comment: Are you familiar with how the web works? HTTP, HTML, server/client, etc? Because `MessageBox.Show` is from Windows Forms. It will show a `MessageBox` on the machine that the code is running on, in this case the server (assuming the account is an account that can access the UI). You will need to to ditch the MessageBox and learn how to do things the Web way.

Comment: Yes - winforms isn't going to work for a web application.  You might be able to WPF though.

Comment: @DavidP What do you mean "You might be able to WPF"? That will result in the exact same problem!

Comment: @mason, the dialog cannot be seen not due to the account, but session. IIS runs in system session, so the dialog would be displayed in that session, and logged on users might see the error message because of session isolation.

Comment: WPF can be used on the web (IE only, but...) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480223.aspx

Comment: Mr. Mason ........................i also add a System.Windows.Forms.dll add in refrences but it is failed  when i   host web site on IIS Server Local Host   MessageBox.Show Not work ..................

Answer (score 0):

@David compiling it is easy. You just add the Win Forms reference and voila!

Sir send Link for  Win Forms reference for MessageBox.Show() in a web application. compile and host on IIS server

Answer (score 0):

The messagebox is meant to be used for windows desktop applications. it will not show when deployed as it will try to open a message box on the server's desktop instead of the web application. If you want to show messages on a .Net application I know of 2 solutions.

1.) You can use a Javascript Alert client side

2.) Use a hidden div on the page - give it the runat='server' property and you can populate the div with a new message from the server side as well as show and hide it.